# Delphi XE8 DCC32 cannot find runtime packages

Tags: delphi, compilation, command

I try to use DCC32 to compile Delphi project from Delphi XE8 but I cannot compile with runtime packages.  In -LU options, I can only specify Delphi system package.  It seems to able to locate the dcp from Delphi system directory.  But if I add a third party package which is installed in other location, DCC32 will say runtime package not found.

The following work

-LUrtl;dbrtl;vcl;vcldb;vclx;vclie;vclimg;vclsmp;vclactnband;tee;teeui;inet;xmlrtl;soaprtl;dsnap;designide;IndySystem;IndyCore;IndyProt
ocols

The following does not work

-LUrtl;dbrtl;vcl;vcldb;vclx;vclie;vclimg;vclsmp;vclactnband;tee;teeui;inet;xmlrtl;soaprtl;dsnap;designide;IndySystem;IndyCore;IndyProt
ocols;kbmMemRunDX8Std

Report kbmMemRunDX8Std not found.  Anyone know how to setup the cfg file to search for runtime package?  All other search options are for different files

-U for source units (*.pas, *.dfm)
-I for include units (*.inc)
-R for resource units (*.res)
-O for object units (*.obj)

Appreciate if anyone know the answer.  (Same problem if I use MSBuild).

Finally, the --depends option does not work, but this is not the question.

Comment: Please ignore --depends not work.  It work and the output was in the same directory as the exe.